# Equivalent ms access query in vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, vb6, ms-access-2007

I want a vba query to generate the same output as

```
SELECT Count(INFO.plate_no) AS CountOfplate_no
FROM Info
HAVING ((date_time Between #10/8/2012 20:55:20# And #10/10/2012 14:5:50#));
```

Comment: So what's wrong with that query? Calling it from VBA doesn't change the queries you can pass to the database.

Comment: Do you know how to implement any query in vba?

Answer (score 0):

does it work? [HAVING (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms180199.aspx)

```
SELECT Count(INFO.plate_no) AS CountOfplate_no 
FROM INFO 
WHERE((date_time Between #10/8/2012 20:55:20# And #10/10/2012 14:5:50#));
```